Github Action failing on running the Dremio API call
Dremio API call when done from Github Action is failing.
# For more information see: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-python

name: Dremio Workflow

on:
  workflow_call:
env:
  dremio_url: ${{secrets.DREMIO_URL}}
  dremio_pat: ${{secrets.DREMIO_PAT}}
  envior: 'dev'
permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:

  env-set:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: PROD
    steps:
      - name: Check out code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
      - name: Set up Python 3.11.4
        uses: actions/setup-python@v3
        with:
          python-version: "3.11.4"
      - name: Downloading requirements
        run: |
          python -m pip install requests

      - name: Deploying against CR# ${{github.event.inputs.change_request_id}}
        run: |
          python .github/workflows/dremio.py --DREMIO_URL ${{secrets.DREMIO_URL}} --DREMIO_PAT ${{secrets.DREMIO_PAT}} 

Interestingly the code works on local, but fails on github action.
The failure message is :
Exception occured: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='*****', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v3/catalog/by-path/dev/report/ap/ap_file (Caused by NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f41ce193ed0>: Failed to resolve '*****' ([Errno -5] No address associated with hostname)")) Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
This is the snippet of the python code which is ruuning:
try:
        url = f"{DREMIO_URL}/by-path/{environment}/{report}/{datasubject}/{r_name}"
        payload = ""
        headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {PAT}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        print("URL ",url)
        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

        return "Success", response.text

    except Exception as e:
        return "Failure", f"Exception occured: {e}"


What does this line print? print("URL ",url) Are you passing in the secrets to the reusable workflow?

yes i am, the reusable workflow is referenced to the same repo as the main workflow

Then why is the hostname can not be resolved: Failed to resolve ... No address associated with hostname. Does the secret have a typo?
